# Getting Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: attempted to open sandboxed jar as Trusted-Only

Tags: jarsigner

We need to sign all 5 `.class` java files. That we have done by creating a `.jar` file and signed it too. But while executing my web application it is showing below error message in Java Console

```
java.lang.SecurityException: attempted to open sandboxed jar https://xxxxxxxxxxx.com/xxxx/JavaApplet.jar as Trusted-Only
at com.sun.deploy.security.CPCallbackHandler$ParentElement.checkResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.checkResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getResource(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.findClassHelper(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: attempted to open sandboxed jar https://xxxxxxxxxxx.com/xxxx/JavaApplet.jar as Trusted-Only*
```

I am not sure about this error. I have signed Jar 3-4 times after getting this error but I am getting same error again again.

Please can anybody help me if I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Check your Manifest.mf file of jar. This should contain the `Trusted-Library: true` if you are using [MixedCode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/mixed_code.html)(Applet called from the javascript) and your files are self signed. oracle has released latest security updates in **Java 7 update 21**. According to the release notes you must sign your code with **CA certificates** only, else JRE will treat your code as malicious. oracle is totally deprecating the Mixedcode. Please check the [release notes of latest updates](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u21-relnotes-1932873.html). But before adding the attribute `Trusted-Library: true` in **manifest.mf** make sure you are aware of the effects of the attribute.